# Sudoers permission without loging in as root

Tags: 10.10, sudo

I am a new user to Ubuntu 10.10
My problem is when I start my machine it takes me to login screen of Ubuntu
but I didn't get option for logging in as user or root
I know my root password and all
even cant make a ssh request
I goggled it I got to know to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
it takes me to login of user

in this user after logging I am unable to write `sudo` commands

After searching for a while I came to know that permission to sudo might be crating a problem
permission to a sudo must be 440 I think which is 777 now

How to start up with my root access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you haven't touched sudo or changed anything on `/etc` then its just your fear and you should read what Sergey has to say. Apart from that check if the file permission part is correct. Just do `ls -l /etc | grep sudoers` and see if the output is somthing like this:

```
-r--r-----  1 root    root       574 2011-03-25 20:34 sudoers
```

where `-r--r-----` part shows your permission to be 440 anything other than that should be changed to that as far as I know. If you can login as root on rescue mode, you can easily change file permission with  `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` command. If you are not allowed `sudo` command at all you may need an external live-usb to recover. Content of `/etc/sudoers` or `visudo` should look like this[atleast in my case]:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: +1 You got my problem...Thanks for that...can you please give me step to fix my problem with live USB....I am not able to add permission to it...or else should I edit my visudo file and make it as yours..

Comment: Try this http://superuser.com/questions/306182/chmod-sudoers-without-using-sudo

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu, you generally never log in as root directly - especially you do not start an X session as root. Also, by default root password is not set/unknown so you can't log in directly as root.

The initial user created during Ubuntu installation has an ability to "sudo" - i.e.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

sudo then asks you for **YOUR** password, not root password.

In a terminal session, if you want to execute many commands as root (or maybe even start some graphical programs as root), you type

```
sudo su
```

and again enter YOUR password. This will start a root terminal session.

The "original" Ubuntu user can make other users "admins" so they can execute commands as root too.

Does it solve your problem?

Comment: Isn't it `sudo -i` instead of `sudo su`?

Comment: It's not "instead", `sudo su` and `sudo -i` do roughly the same - open a superuser shell after asking for user's password. There may be some tiny obscure differences but for the purpose of the question they're identical.

Comment: Got it. I noticed one difference is that `sudo -i` navigates to root's home while `sudo su` stays in the current directory. In any case, I've never had a `sudo` command ask for the currently logged in user's password (that would be `ubuntu` in my case). Maybe because I'm already logged in, or maybe because I'm using public key authentication.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your sudo permission got messed up. This is what my permissions are for sudo and ls:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 168800 2011-04-15 21:32 /usr/bin/sudo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 105776 2011-02-23 19:54 /bin/ls
```

The key thing here is to have the setuid bit - which allows an application to change the user id: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid Which might have been disabled.

If you need to restore sudo, you can boot Ubuntu into "recovery mode", where it should give you the ability to open up a root shell.

If you feel that your permissions might be messed up, I think running `dpkg-reconfigure sudo` while in recovery mode can help.

After that, you can run `visudo` to open up the sudoers file and edit it to add your user.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've read the manual on sudo by typing in a prompt 
  'man sudo' and it really is broken the easiest way for a new user to fix almost anything is the reinstall. If you don't have the time or you have a lot installed already I recommend not using my answer.